# Misunderstood to have downvoted someone?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, user-interface

I'm not fluent enough in the inner workings of EL&U to prove it, but I get the distinct sense that certain posters suspect me of downvoting them when in fact I haven't. None of the related questions above really deal with this issue, and it has me mildly concerned.

I wouldn't presume, so early in my tenure here, to mark someone down in any event (and feel it's unlikely I ever will), but in the instances where the downvoter gives no comment to accompany his action, I feel as though suspicions are raised generally. Maybe others feel the same; as a novice, I certainly do.

[There may be a completely rational answer to this -"someone can go to your homepage and check out your stats"- for which I'd be grateful.]

Comment: what is your actual.. question? I don't understand.

Comment: Is there any visual indication of who has downvoted an answer? I've seen a number of respondents voted down and, in the absence of any illuminating comment, having to ask "why?" I suppose it's just the chronological order which juxtaposes comments, but it's happened to me more than once, and I feel like saying, "it wasn't me." [This may be an absolute non-issue or a fact of life for a wiki, in which case I'm sorry and you're welcome to kill this thread.]

Comment: The answer to "Is there any visual indication of who has downvoted an answer" is no. There's no sort of indicator anywhere, at least nothing accessible to users. AFAIK moderators can't see it either.

Answer (score 1):

You have not downvoted anyone, as evidenced by your [user page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/4752/fortunate1) in the *Votes* section. Which posts you have voted on can only be seen by Stack Exchange developers, but not moderators or other users. (Occasionally, people do downvote accidentally, because they mistakenly think that it will cancel up an upvote, but this is not the case here.)

If people do accuse you of downvoting them, and you care about it, then simply reply *calmly* that you have not downvoted them (but if you can, provide explanations why someone else might have done so to help the poster improve his/her post). Otherwise, just leave it alone.